# XPath how to get Python

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to us Xpath to get the text in the example below the "7061 MAIN ST"

```
 <TD ROWSPAN="2">
            <FONT FACE="Arial,helvetica" SIZE="-1">


                7061 MAIN ST

            </FONT>
            </TD>
```

However it's not working well for me.
I tried the following below and it won't work.
On a search in the source that's the only one that has the attribute Rowspan="2"

```
searchResults = tree.xpath('//*[@rowspan="2"]/@text')
self.response.out.write(searchResults)
searchResults = tree.xpath('//*[@rowspan="2"]/font/@text')
self.response.out.write(searchResults)
searchResults = tree.xpath('//*[@rowspan="2"]/font[text()]')
self.response.out.write(searchResults)
```

What shoudl i do to get the text?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried Chrome "Copy XPath" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
searchResults = tree.xpath('//td[@rowspan="2"]/font/text()')
```

will make `searchResults` equal to the list

```
['\n\n\n                7061 MAIN ST\n\n            ']
```

(Note you may want to use the `str.strip` method to remove the whitespace from both ends of the string.)

---

1. `@text` refers to the *attribute* `text`. For example, `rowspan` is
   an attribute of `td`, and `face` is an attribute of `font`. Here, we
   want the actual text, not an attribute. So use `text()` instead.
2. Also, if we omit `font` from the XPath, as in

   ```
   //td[@rowspan="2"]/text()
   ```

   then we are retrieving the text associated with the `td` tag. That
   would be empty in the HTML you posted. We want the text associated
   with the `font` tag, so we include `font` in the XPath:

   ```
   //td[@rowspan="2"]/font/text()
   ```
3. Finally, know that brackets `[...]` indicate a "such that"
   relationship in XPath. For example, `td[@rowspan="2"]` matches `td`
   tags *such that* the `rowspan` attribute equals `"2"`.  So
   `font[text()]` matchs `font` tags *such that* it contains some
   `text()`. It returns the `font` tag itself. Since we want the text,
   not the tag, we use `font/text()` instead of `font[text()]`.